# Copying Data from specific Columns, and multiple rows from multiple excel files into 1 using vba/macro

Tags: sql, vba, excel

hoping someone can help me, I am working on a project for work and I have hit a brick wall. I am new to coding, and through various trials, and research I have compiled a code which only does part of what i require.

the principle is simple, I have a few hundred excel sheets, which i want to pull data from specific columns into a new sheet with column headers. So far, my code pulls in the first row from each file in the directory, however I need this to read all the rows until it goes blank, this can vary greatly, which is why i cant use a standard range.

So far, this is my code:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
Dim MyFolder As String 
Dim FiletoList As String 
Dim NextRow As Long 

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.Title = "Please select a folder"
.Show
.AllowMultiSelect = False

If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
    Exit Sub
End If
MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With


FiletoList = Dir(MyFolder & "Marking Sheet Ref*.xls")
Range("A1").Value = "Sitting Number"
Range("B1").Value = "Student Name"
Range("C1").Value = "Member Number"
Range("D1").Value = "1"
Range("E1").Value = "2"
Range("F1").Value = "3"
Range("G1").Value = "4"
Range("H1").Value = "5"
Range("I1").Value = "6"
Range("J1").Value = "7"
Range("K1").Value = "8"
Range("L1").Value = "9"
Range("M1").Value = "10"
Range("N1").Value = "11"
Range("O1").Value = "12"
Range("P1").Value = "13"
Range("Q1").Value = "14"
Range("R1").Value = "15"
Range("S1").Value = "16"
Range("T1").Value = "17"
Range("U1").Value = "18"
Range("V1").Value = "Total % Mark"
Range("W1").Value = "Final Grade"
Range("X1").Value = "Moderator % Mark"
Range("Y1").Value = "Moderator Final Grade"
Range("Z1").Value = "Unit Code"
Range("AA1").Value = "Program Code"
Range("AB").Value = "Marker Name"
Range("AC1").Value = "Country"

'Find the next empty row in the list
NextRow = Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
NextRow = NextRow + 1 ' skip a line

'Do whilst the dir function returns an Excel workbook
 Do While FiletoList <> ""
 Cells(NextRow, 1).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C1"
Cells(NextRow, 2).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C2"
Cells(NextRow, 3).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C3"
Cells(NextRow, 4).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C5"
Cells(NextRow, 5).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C6"
Cells(NextRow, 6).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C7"
Cells(NextRow, 7).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C8"
Cells(NextRow, 8).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C9"
Cells(NextRow, 9).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C10"
Cells(NextRow, 10).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C11"
Cells(NextRow, 11).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C12"
Cells(NextRow, 12).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C13"
Cells(NextRow, 13).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C14"
Cells(NextRow, 14).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C15"
Cells(NextRow, 15).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C16"
Cells(NextRow, 16).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C17"
Cells(NextRow, 17).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C18"
Cells(NextRow, 18).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C19"
Cells(NextRow, 19).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C20"
Cells(NextRow, 20).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C21"
Cells(NextRow, 21).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C22"
Cells(NextRow, 22).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C23"
Cells(NextRow, 23).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C24"
Cells(NextRow, 24).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C32"
Cells(NextRow, 25).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C33"
Cells(NextRow, 26).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C25"
Cells(NextRow, 27).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C27"
Cells(NextRow, 28).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C30"
Cells(NextRow, 29).Formula = "='" & MyFolder & "[" & FiletoList & "]Marking Sheet'! R11C31"
NextRow = NextRow + 1 'Move to next row
FiletoList = Dir 'Dir returns the next Excel workbook in the folder
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This returns the first row (row 11) of each excel sheet that I wish to copy the data from, however there might be 1 row, or 1000 rows. all of this data needs to be captured, and I cannot work out what I have missed out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It has to be specific to start from row 11, and the columns provided are also specific to the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will need a second loop INSIDE the loop you have defined already.  Your code is getting one row of data and then moving on to the next file.

The inner loop needs to determine the number of rows in the range (as you have already identified).  This code is one way of doing that (for a range in Sheet called "Data").

```
   endRowNo = Sheets("Data").Cells(.Rows.Count, ColNo).End(xlUp).Row
```

Instead of looping through the rows you may find your code could be shortened by copying the whole data range in one go, assuming that it is in the order you require.

[See this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760(v=office.15).aspx)

You might also consider using a loop to populate your "numerical" headings in order to shorten your code.  It is worth learning/using the Cells notation makes it easier to manipulate ranges within a loop.

[Check out this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291308)

Finally, take care when using ON ERROR RESUME NEXT this may hide coding errors and make resolving them more difficult.  You may find learning a bit more about basic error handling useful.

[This link may help](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

Hope this helps.